# Show activity that running in background

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android activity that downloads content from the web. The activity have progress bar and some indications about download. The user can press back and go to the main activity app. How can i make button that will show the download activity?

The code:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.myapp.DOWNLOAD");
startActivity(i);
```

Starts again the activity and that is not what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your AndroidManifest.xml, modify your download activity to include the `launchMode="singleInstance"` value. For example:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".DownloadActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```

This will create only one instance of DownloadActivity. Any subsequent requests to show this activity will pull the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Class1.this, Class2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This code will start the Class2.class from scratch, the Class2 is running and i wish just to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Design wise, downloading can be done by a service running a separate thread. The service will not terminate when your dialog goes away. The [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) usage example has some code for it.

Comment: The download activity does uses AsyncTask thread. The service is not terminated and i can see in LogCut that it continues to work, but my problem is to show that class again after exit.

Comment: If you want to keep your design, You need to maintain a reference to AsyncTask in the calling activity. Pass this object to the Activity on Starting it. Activity can access progress data through calling methods on AsyncTask.